# Can you add a custom button on delivered Report Page in Salesforce.com or custom link?

Tags: reporting, custom-button

Can you add a Custom button on a OOTB Report Page in the same line where u have Run Report button? 
OR
Add a custom link along where you have 'Help for this Page' link?

[image]

Comment: what's OOTB please?

Comment: i believe it means Out Of The Box

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot do that and I don't think there is any practical workaround to that.